# Angular serve fails because of Unexpected character '#' which is not in my source code

Tags: angular

When I try to build by angular app I get this error :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/bin.js 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> #!/usr/bin/env node
| "use strict";
| Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Is there a way to fix it?
I already deleted my node_modules folder but it didn't help.

There seems to be a problem with this component:

tree.component.ts :

```
import { Component, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tree',
    templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css']
})
/** wkz component*/
export class TreeComponent {
  @Input() wkz;
  @Output() notify = new EventEmitter();
    /** wkz ctor */
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

tree.component.html

```
<div> test</div>
```

tree.component.css

```
a{
    color:black;
}
```

This component is used nowhere, only referenced in my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { TreeComponent } from './tree/tree.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@J Doe,
Good morning. Could you please display your Folder Structure. Also what html files exist? Many thanks.

**PS:** As I have less than 50 points, I cannot directly add the comment to your query.

**Sample Code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductDto } from '../interfaces/ProductDto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-alerts',
  templateUrl: './product-alerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-alerts.component.css']
})
export class ProductAlertsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product: ProductDto;
  @Output() notifyUser = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: @Input() data;
@Output() notify = new EventEmitter();

If I remove these lines the compilation works again.

Comment: I added some info

Comment: Thanks Give me 5 minutes I will look into the code.

Comment: Could you please change the EventEmitter to import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

Comment: That worked, Thank you very much. I have no clue, where this import comes from.

Answer (score 3):

You have imported EventEmitter from protactor which throws error while building.

```
import { Component,EventEmitter,OnInit, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
```

This usually happens when you try to use the dependencies without importing. Your code Editor tries to add the imports which it finds for quick fix.

@Viswanatha Swamy answer is also same. Just I have imported all the dependencies in one line

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is wrong.

Your import:

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'protractor';
```

The right import:

```
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
```